# Laravel - How to store Input::old into variable

Tags: php, forms, input, laravel

I know these are similar question like this here in SO, but seems like all are specific circumstances.

As straight as my question's title, is this possible? How can I? I Thought it was easy but not

I know about Input::flash() and it **successful** retain the old input when I do the **FIRST** browser reload. **But fail** at the **next** reload. So that's why I think I need to store the Input::old into variable.

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

It does exactly that, flash data is only available for the next request. If you want to retain flashed data for the subsequent request you can use.

```
Session::reflash();
```

Comment: Thanks David, but not sure because I already try Session::put & Session::get and still no luck.